# Text near image (plot) in RMD PDF

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have made a pdf from my rmd, but there is a pie chart that takes a tiny space. I would like to make the text that comes after it to fall next to it instead of falling under it. I know that this can easily be done with HTML, but I want to convert it to pdf. Is there any way to do it or should I just give up?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with some custom option definitions in the knitr hooks:

````
---
title: "SO"
author: "Julian_Hn"
date: "July 20, 2020"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{wrapfig}
---


   ```{r, include = F}
normalOut <- knitr::knit_hooks$get("plot")  # capture defaul plot behaviour of knitr
knitr::knit_hooks$set(plot = function(Out, options) {   # define new plot behaviour
  Out <- normalOut(Out, options)  # apply normal stuff specified in the other options
  if(!is.null(options$wrapfig)) {  # if custom option wrapfig is specified
    # replace the default figure latex code with wrapfigure code
    wrapf <- sprintf("\\begin{wrapfigure}{%s}{%g\\textwidth}", options$wrapfig[[1]], options$wrapfig[[2]])
    Out  <- gsub("\\begin{figure}", wrapf, Out, fixed = T)  
    Out  <- gsub("{figure}", "{wrapfigure}", Out, fixed = T)  
  }
  return(Out)
})
    ```


Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscingvitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a,magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuadafames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urnafringilla ultrices. 


  ```{r echo=F, wrapfig = list("R", .5), fig.cap = "Test Wrapfigure", fig.width=5, fig.height = 5, out.width = ".5\\textwidth", fig.align="right"}
plot(1:10,1:10)```

Duisnibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim rutrum.Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacuslibero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et, tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum, eratligula aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis. Suspendisse utmassa. Cras nec ante. Pellentesque a nulla. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes,nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam tincidunt urna. Nulla ullamcorper vestibulum turpis. Pellentesque cursusluctus mauris.Nulla malesuada porttitor diam.  Donec felis erat, congue non, volutpat at, tincidunt tristique, libero.Vivamus viverra fermentum felis.
````

Note the use of LaTeX package `wrapfig` and the options specified in the header. You can then always call your plot routines with the `wrapfig`option and the appropiate parameters to wrap your text around plots.

[image]